# can't get array of images using JQuery, js, jsp

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, arrays, jsp

I have jsp page where I get products from database and for each product i have several images. i want to create simple image slider in JS for each product, but i can't get an array of images on JS. i try to do it by id in img tag, but have null. i understand that i need to use JQuery and i need to get a link on every product img, but don't know how, maybe somebody can help me.

Jsp

```
<c:forEach items="${produkt}" var="produkt">
<div class="produkt-container" style=" border: 1px solid #ccc; display: inline-block;text-align:left;">
<a   href="produkt${produkt.id}" >${produkt.model}</a>
<%--<img src="${produkt.images[o]}" alt="">--%>
 <div id="img-container"  style="max-width: 280px">
   <button class="btnClass" id="prev" onclick="plusImg(-1)">&#10094; 
</button>
<c:forEach  items="${produkt.images}" var="image">
    <img src="${image}"  id="img-list"  alt="" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 260px">
</c:forEach>
   <button class="btnClass" id="next" onclick="plusImg(1)">&#10095;</button>
</div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

simple slider in js

```
<script>

var count = 1;
sliderImg(count);

function plusImg(n) {
sliderImg(count += n);
}

function sliderImg (n) {
    var i;
 //  var ar  = $('.produkt-container').find('a');
 //  var x = $(this).attr('href');

var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".img-list");
if(n > x.length){count =1}
if(n < 1){count = x.length}
for (i =0; i<x.length; i++){
    x[i].style.display ="none";
}
x[count-1].style.display = "block";

console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Where are you including this script at on the page?  In the `head` or `body`?  Also `document.getElementsByClassName(".img-list");` does not take a selector.  It expects just the class name, so take the period off.

Comment: Also as a side note, your jsp loops are repeating ids in the markup, which is invalid markup.

Comment: this is a problem i dont know how write a link on images for every produkts. i includ script on the body

Comment: i include script on the body on jsp

Comment: yes after the logic

Comment: Ok, so since your logic is after the elements are created, fix your issue with the `getElementsByClassName` argument and see what issues you have then.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense to me. You can't create a link for each image tag or you can't create array of images in JS? Why not just wrap each image tag with an anchor tag?

Comment: thanks, i juat dont know if it is posible to  create a link for each image. so will be wrap each image tag with an anchor tag